# Pegar um atributo de uma classe em javascript

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma lista com todos os meus amigos do facebook.

Consegui criar a primeira linha do código, que faz com que eu pegue todos os meus amigos e guarde em uma variável dentro de um array, como é mostrado abaixo:

```
var info = document.getElementsByClassName("_52jh _5pxc");
```

Em seguida, quando peço pra ver os elementos é mostrada a seguinte mensagem:

```
info[0];
<h3 class="_52jh _5pxc"><a href="/urldouser?ref=bookmarks">Nome Do Usuário</a></h3>
```

O que eu preciso fazer, é pegar o "Nome do Usuário" e não estou conseguindo, tentei usar o

```
var names = info[0].getAtributte("a");
```

Mas me retorna null, de qual forma eu poderia resolver isto, a ponto de conseguir pegar o que se encontra após a abertura. `>"Nome Do Usuário"<`.

Acredito que seja uma resposta simples, entretanto, estou iniciando a fase de web agora e tenho algumas dificuldades, agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O elemento `a` não é um atributo de `h3` mas sim descendente direto, daí não dar para usar `getAtributte`.

Mas podes usar assim, que usa como ponto de partida o próprio elemento:

```
var names = info[0].querySelector("a").innerHTML;
```

Na verdade podes pegar todos fazendo assim:

```
var nomes = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('._52jh._5pxc a'), function(el) {
    return el.innerHTML;
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zx7pyjm3/

Comment: Muito obrigado!